# What do browsers want for the Content-Type header on json ajax responses?

Tags: ajax, json, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I am returning some json which needs to be handled by javascript as the response to an XMLHTTPRequest.

If I set the response's content type to "text/plain", all browsers but Chrome will accept it and pass it to my JS with no problem. However, Chrome will wrap the response in

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
```

before passing it to my javascript.

If I set the response's content type to the "proper"  "application/json" all browsers but Firefox will accept it and pass it to my JS with no problem. Firefox, however will ask to save or open the response as a file.

What's the correct, cross-browser Content-Type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The *right* JSON content type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)

Comment: Maybe. Except that thread has the *wrong* answer (if you use the answer there, firefox behaves like a petulant child)

Comment: How does Firefox misbehave?  If you're referring to saving and downloading, try the "Open in Browser" suggestion as referred to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94767

Comment: Have observed this odd behaviour with Chrome. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411670/tab-and-pre-wrapped-around-json-output-in-chrome

Answer (score 9):

You may solve the issue by parsing the response into the JSON object by using jQuery funcion parseJSON - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

The parameter you pass into the function is the JSON object string, which you extract from the response data:

```
function AjaxResponse (data) {  // AJAX post callback 
  var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data.substring(data.indexOf("{"), data.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
}
```

Tested (besides Chrome which problem this solves) in FF and IE8 for the following simple JSON result, for other browsers and more complex responses no guarantees...

---

*NOTE: the content type in this case is text/plain or text/html I think - I've used the following ASP.Net MVC function to return the result*

```
ContentResult System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Content(string content);
```

*Where I returned the JSON object like*

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer 
    = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonResponse = jsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new { IArticleMediaId = 0
        , ImageUrl = Url.Content(fullImgPath)
        });
return Content(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

In  ajaxFileUpload.js in uploadCallback() replace

```
io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML.innerHTML
```

with

```
$(io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML).html()
```