# How can I return actual JSON using Drupal?

Tags: ajax, json, drupal, drupal-7

I'd like to implement a simple AJAX function locally that allows me to autocomplete node titles of already existing nodes as the user types. To that end, I need the ability to have an API that I can search on node titles. The problem is that when I output raw JSON, it comes surrounded by tags. So, no matter what I do, I keep getting...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"> {json here}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried implementing a custom page template that only outputs content already, that produced the same results. Here is how I am currently doing this, in my module file...

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function content_relation_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['api'] = array(
        'title' => 'Search',
        'page callback' => 'content_relation_get',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function content_relation_get($term = '') {
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript; utf-8');
    $var = json_encode(
        db_query("SELECT nid,title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT 5", array(":title" => $term.'%'))->fetchAll()
    );
    echo $var;
    exit(0);
}
```

How can I return JUST raw JSON?

Comment: A very useful question indeed and a timesaver! This can help you set up a web service in drupal on your own (when you don't need the heavyweight modules like _services_) using just the _hook\_menu_ and a callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'Drupal' way is using [`drupal_json_output()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) and [`drupal_exit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7).

```
$data = db_query("SELECT nid,title FROM {node} WHERE title LIKE :title LIMIT 5", array(":title" => $term.'%'))->fetchAll();

drupal_json_output($data);

drupal_exit();
```

**UPDATE**

I've just put your code, as is, into a module and all I get when requesting `http://site.com/api` is the expected JSON, there are no tags. The problem won't be anything to do with Drupal, more likely to do with server/browser configuration.

This link may help:

[What do browsers want for the Content-Type header on json ajax responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002109/what-do-browsers-want-for-the-content-type-header-on-json-ajax-responses)

Comment: This way is "more correct", but it turns out this actually did output raw JS. Thank you though.

Comment: You beat me to it, I just updated my answer to that effect :)

Answer (score 2):

This actually DID output raw JSON - Chrome was adding the html wrapping. Viewing the output in command line cURL showed that this did output raw JSON.

Comment: Chrome appears to have a very strict sense of what can be displayed as a webpage; so it adds HTML and PRE tags to your JSON output which is confusing. View Source and you'll see there are no tags there. Good comment.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the exit(0); and it should work. If your page callback doesn't return anything then the normal theme handlers don't get called so you get raw output.

That said, due to the rather poor performance of Drupal, for decent response times you're better off making a small standalone script that talks to the drupal DB, so you don't pay the rather heavy startup costs of a drupal request when you don't need of that functionality.

Comment: Knocking a CMS while solving the problem might get you that even if it is true. ;)

The middle road way might be to bootstrap drupal to the database level only with a call to drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE) and avoid all of the heavy module overhead.