# Detect MIME type of ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, mime-types

I'm trying to load an image on my site, and if the image generation fails I want to display a text message as to why it failed. Best way to do this?

This is what I've tried, but the image data is apparently interpreted as a string. (I get a bunch of gibberish in my imgContainer).

```
function GetImage(id) {
    $.get('ajax/getImage', { Id: id }, function (data) {
        if (typeof data == "string") {
            $('div#imgContainer').html(data);
        } else {
            $('img#imgViewer').attr('src', data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**

It seems my error is more that you can't set image data to the src attribute as I'm doing above. From what I can tell, you need to set the src straight to the link, like:

```
$('div#imgContainer').html('<img src="ajax/getImage" />');
```

But this doesn't give you the option to check the datatype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do browsers want for the Content-Type header on json ajax responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002109/what-do-browsers-want-for-the-content-type-header-on-json-ajax-responses)

Answer (score 2):

You could instead have your ajax call return a content type of "application/json" in the event of an error.  Something like:

```
{"error": "something bad happened"}
```

Then in your callback, you can check if it's an object or string:

```
$.ajax('/some/url')
    .done(function(response){
        if($.isPlainObject(response)){
            //....
        }
        else{
            //....
        }
    })
```