# How do I encode JSON in PHP via jQuery Ajax post data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an HTML form and send data to php file when hitting submit button.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "text.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        amount: amount,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: email
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("ok");
        $("#result").text(data);
    }
});
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
    $amount      = $_POST["amount"];
    $firstName   = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName    = $_POST["lastName"];
    $email       = $_POST["email"];
    if(isset($amount)){
        $data = array(
            "amount"     => $amount,
            "firstName"  => $firstName,
            "lastName"   => $lastName,
            "email"      => $email
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

The result is [object object]. I want a type like:

```
{"Amount":"12.34", "FirstName":"Any", "LastName":"Tester", "Email":"a.test@something.com"}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `The result is [object object]`... yes, that's what you'll get if JS casts an object to a string. Your JSON may be correct; you're just not examining it properly. Try using `console.log()` instead. Also, use the dev tools to look at the http response that PHP sends back -- you should be able to see exactly what the data looks like.

Comment: In terms of dev tools you can give FirePHP4Chrome a spin.

Comment: Are you setting the content header from PHP to be application/json?

Comment: I agree with Spudley and if you just want to ensure try to console.log or alert data.Amount or data.FirstName and it will give you the value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Code example with JSON.stringify:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>jQuery Test</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#submit").click(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "text.php",
                       type: "POST",
                       data: {
                           amount: $("#amount").val(),
                           firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
                           lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
                           email: $("#email").val()
                       },
                       dataType: "JSON",
                       success: function (jsonStr) {
                           $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <form name="contact" id="contact" method="post">
            Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/><br/>
            firstName: <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/><br/>
            lastName: <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/><br/>
            email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get It!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### text.php

```
<?php
    $amount      = $_POST["amount"];
    $firstName   = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName    = $_POST["lastName"];
    $email       = $_POST["email"];
    if(isset($amount)){
        $data = array(
            "amount"     => $amount,
            "firstName"  => $firstName,
            "lastName"   => $lastName,
            "email"      => $email
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your object is most likely being passed properly. It's the way you're capturing the result that returns `[object object]` as @Spudley explained. The console doesn't know how to display the construct but you can display specific attributes using the `object.attribute` syntax. Use `console.log()` on the JS side or the code below for a prettified output.

```
// Indent with tabs
// Data is the parameter sent to the success function in the ajax handler
JSON.stringify( data , null, '\t');
```

From [How can I pretty-print JSON in (unix) shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line)

Also Temporarily remove `dataType` on the ajax handler if you sense there's a bug somewhere. Getting the ouput to show on a GET request should do. Change this back to POST for any operation that modifies something like a database delete or alter.

Lastly, modify the header as shown in @GroovyCarrot's answer. If you're using Chrome the extra whitespace seems to be a bug: [Tab and pre wrapped around JSON output in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411670/tab-and-pre-wrapped-around-json-output-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

At the top of your PHP script and see what you get back

Hope that helps!

Edit: Forgot to mention you should access your values like so: `data.amount`

Comment: good idea yet it will not solve the problem :) Like James Poulson sais the json object is passed correctly but the objects toString method returns [object object]

Comment: It is really unnecessary, as `jQuery` really does not care about it

Comment: I did add a comment on correctly accessing returned values for the JSON object, I agree this answer was a tad brief

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly insert a JSON object to a dom. JSON object `toString()` method will always give u [object object], that is why you are getting this. You ve to parse the data by using 
`JSON.stringify(data)` or you have to run `$.each(data,function(val){ $("#result").append(val) })`.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting resulting object to string instead of displaying it.

Instead of result, if you want print object inside some wrapper, you can do something like this:

```
var text = '{';

for(var i in data) {
  var value = data[i];

  text += '"'+i+'":"'+value+'", ';
}

text += '}';

$('#result').text(text);
```

But you may consider that `console.log` is much easier and faster way to see the response in json format.

Comment: It's rather for browsers that do not support JSON.strigify