# HTTP 500 error when accessing JSON file using REST web service in Firefox. Works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, firefox, rest

I'm building a few REST web services and I'm facing an interesting issue..

I've built some error handling so that when the server throws a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, a JSON payload is still provided instead of the default error page on a browser. By doing so, I can provide the user with a more detailed error response so they can figure out what went wrong.

This works great in Chrome and Safari however, in Firefox the default error page appears and I get a "File not found" error back. I know Firefox handles JSON payloads differently to Webkit browsers, as instead of processing them directly in the browser, an actual .JSON file is provided.

I'm confused as to how I can go about handling this very clear issue that is specific to Firefox. Any help would be great!

Comment: hmm indeed a odd error. Can you validate that the request datatype in both browsers is the same? Not sure what you're serverside language is, but maybe it tries to render the wrong type?

Comment: Hi Manuel, yes they are exactly the same. I'm trying the exact same URL in both browsers.

Comment: it's not about the url, it's about the request headers that are being send. Could you maybe also post the javascript you use to perform the json call?

Comment: Manuel, should Firefox open the JSON payload even if there is a 500 error?. If so, the javascript should be fine as when I hit the web service within Firefox it doesn't even bring back a payload. Just the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging my web app with JSON/Firefox - Firefox handling of JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94767/debugging-my-web-app-with-json-firefox-firefox-handling-of-json)